# UItableView Cell Resuablity Data getting interchaged while scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, reuseidentifier

[image: Grouped TableView with 4 rows in each Section]

Hi All,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 200, 30)];
        textField.tag = 123;
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        textField.delegate = self;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

    }

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee ID"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Name"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2)
        {
            [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Phone"];
        }
         if (indexPath.row == 3)
        {
            [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Email"];
            UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [saveButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 40)];
            [saveButton setTitle:@"Save Emp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveEmployeeToCoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [saveButton setTag:indexPath.section];
            [cell addSubview:saveButton];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Hi Everyone, 
I am using this piece of code for getting the above output
But when i am scrolling the tableview the output i am getting is

[image: when i am scrolling the tableview the output i am getting]

And if i enter any text in the section and scrolling the text, then the text is changing in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a subview to the cell in one of the cases:

```
[cell addSubview:saveButton];
```

This subview does NOT get removed when you dequeue an old cell. You have to explicitly remove the subview for those cases. This will cause unexpected behaviour.

I really recommend to subclass UITableViewCell and add the components to that subclass. by doing so, you can hide its saveButton-property for the cases where you do not want a saveButton.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `UITextField` and `UIButton` with **tag** in

```
if (cell == nil) 
{
    //Initialize your `UITextField` and `UIButton`
    // also set tag
}
```

And set **frame** of `UITextField` and `UIButton` at out of `if` statement. *(you can get `UITextField` and `UIButton` by its **tag**)*
sure its working for you.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem,try this,

```
UITableViewCell *cell;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

//initialize the tableviewcell outside,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `custom UITableViewCell` & in that class file, you need to get this tied up in the cell Class file . **More importantly**, `need to maintain the datasource for it` .

Don't use the `tag` as 0. I mean, set something similar for every views

`txtView.tag = 25+indexPath.section;`

Comment: I have tried with txtView.tag = 25+indexPath.section, still having the same issue.

Comment: Once I came through the same issue . Just follow my instructions. sure you will get it be done .in briefly , The problem is due to the cell reusing. So the **tag** also gets change as well

Answer (score 0):

Change this "textField.tag = 123" to "text.tag = indexPath.row" in all places. It will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

         UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 200, 30)];
         textField.tag = 123;
         textField.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
         textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
         textField.delegate = self;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    } else {
         //here the cell is reused, so remove the button here
         [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:124] removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee ID"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Name"];
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Phone"];
    }
     if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Email"];
        UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [saveButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 40)];
        [saveButton setTag:124];
        [saveButton setTitle:@"Save Emp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveEmployeeToCoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //[saveButton setTag:indexPath.section];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:saveButton];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue @Akhilrajtr

Answer (score 0):

As per your screen shot there are three visible cell. so when ever you load 4th cell ios will give you reference of 1st cell. here you have already set button for employee email. so that it will visible and again you also set employee id and phone.

So when you reuse the cell your logic should like you need to reset the cell to the default case in this example you can remove that button or hide it and then as per the cell info you should set the cell properties.

I hope you understand the problem.

```
    if (indexPath.row == 3)
                {
                    [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Email"]; 
                    UIButton *saveButton = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:124];

                   if(saveButton == nil) 
                         saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];


                    [saveButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 40)];
                    [saveButton setTag:124];
                    [saveButton setTitle:@"Save Emp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveEmployeeToCoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    //[saveButton setTag:indexPath.section];
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:saveButton];
                }
```

Comment: Yes, i got that, but I want a button in the 4th row, so is that not possible.

Comment: @iOSDev check this if part which I have modify for you.
And also accept the proper answer which has help you for solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it reuse cells in table view

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 200, 30)];
            textField.tag = 123;
            textField.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            textField.delegate = self;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];

           UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
           [saveButton setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 100, 40)];
           [saveButton setTitle:@"Save Emp" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           [saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveEmployeeToCoreData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
           [saveButton setTag:124];
           [cell.contentView addSubview:saveButton];

        }

        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:123];
        UIButton *saveButton =(UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:124];
       saveButton.hidden=YES;
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee ID"];
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Name"];
            }
            else if (indexPath.row == 2)
            {
                [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Phone"];
            }
             if (indexPath.row == 3)
            {
                [textField setPlaceholder:@"Employee Email"];
                saveButton.hidden=NO;
            }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Now I am able to get the button only on the 4th row of the Section, but if I enter any text and Scroll then in one of the section in some rows some data is getting displayed and in some other rows the data is getting displayed.

Comment: table view cell reuse when it visible,if cell will hide cell removed from table view,you will manage data in cellForRowAtIndexPath,every time you assign values for textfield